# Fetch image from non direct HTML link

Tags: ssis, screen-scraping

We have a couple SSIS jobs which nicely fetch images and various expected graphics on websites.  Can't figure out how to fetch an image from the following site (sample).

http://tess2.uspto.gov/ImageAgent/ImageAgentProxy?getImage=77666637

Any thoughts on SSIS techniques?  I'm hoping I don't have to do a screenscrape or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Script Task to fetch the image. The following article gives you a sample code that you can adjust to save an image file instead of text file.

Here is the link : http://www.sqlis.com/sqlis/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx

Comment: if you look at my link though, it isn't a direct link to the image.  I'm not sure I can get at the direct link of the image.

Comment: Even if it's not referencing the direct image file, but the HTTP response contains the bytes of the image.